# Is any function on $(\mathbb S^1)^4$ which is invariant under isometries, invariant under permutations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, symmetry, symmetric-functions

$\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}^1}$This might be silly, but here it goes:

Let $E:(\mathbb{S}^1)^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.

Let $f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ be an isometry of $\mathbb{S}^1$. $f$ induces a map $\tilde f:(\mathbb{S}^1)^4 \to (\mathbb{S}^1)^4$, given by
$$
\tilde f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):=\big(f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3),f(x_4)\big).
$$
Suppose that $E \circ \tilde f = E$ for any $f \in \text{Iso}(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

Is it true that
$$
E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=E(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(3)},x_{\sigma(4)})
$$
for any permutation $\sigma \in S^4$ and any $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in (\mathbb{S}^1)^4$?

I guess that the answer is negative, but I am not sure.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As noted in the comment, this only works for orientation-preserving isometries, not flips. I'll leave it up as "an interesting contribution". :-) ]

Treat $S^1$ as $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$, so that the isometries (which are the rotations) become translations by a fixed amount, i.e. $x \mapsto x + \alpha$, for some fixed $\alpha$.

Pick some $g: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so that there is some $y_0$ with $g(y_0) \ne g(-y_0)$, and define

$$ f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = g(x_2 - x_1)$$

Then $f$ is not invariant under the permutation $(1,2)$.

[For completeness, $g$ could be $g(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$.]

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice construction!. However, your constructed $f$ is invariant under rotations only, and I meant to assume that $f$ is invariant under rotations and reflections. (Although I did not specify this explicitly, I didn't assume in the question the isometries are orientation-preserving). So I will wait to see if someone can say something about this case as well.

Comment: Ah. I was on the verge of adding something about how my characterization of the isometries lacked proof, but "was pretty obvious". Oh well, you're right. Let me see if I can rescue this example.

Comment: Maybe we can average $f$ over all reflections to get a counterexample. (I think this will make $f$ invariant under both rotations and reflections, since averaging won't destroy the rotational invariance).

Comment: I was thinking that the set of all $E$ satisfying the rotational symmetry condition was the same as $\{ g : \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$, via $E(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = g(x_2-x_1, x_3-x_2, x_4-x_3)$ [we lose a dimension because $(x_1 - x_4)$ is dependent on the other three values], and $g$ can be arbitrary. It feels like adding "reflection" should only cut that space in half, or maybe one-eighth, and we should still be able to find a counter example in there.

Comment: Thanks! that is a nice heuristic. I think adding reflection reflections might lose a "full continuous degree of freedom", but I am not sure. Anyway, I tried the averaging idea; I think it works, but I have actually found a simpler idea, so I wrote it as a separate answer. Thanks for the interesting discussion and the inspiration. Your answer definitely made me think more thoroughly on the question.

Comment: Definitely a fun problem; enjoyed thinking about it and nice to see your answer, "stupid" though it may be. If you want to play with it further, I think cutting down the dimension to $(S^1)^3$, and then $(S^1)^2$, could be looked at. Also, I'm still wondering how the map $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \mapsto (x_2-x_1, x_3-x_2, x_4-x_3, x_1-x_4)$ on $(S^1)^4$ works, especially if we limit to orientation preserving isometries. I guess it collapses the space to a codim-1 subspace, and we can have the function be arbitrary there? Makes sense, but I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 2):

OK, as the question is stated, the answers is negative, for "stupid" reasons:

Take $E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\|x_1-x_2\|$. Then $E$ invariant under isometries, but is not invariant under the permutation $(1,3)$.

**Here is a more interesting example, where $E$ depends non-trivially on all four points:**
$$
E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\|x_1-x_2\|+\sum_{i<j}\|x_i-x_j\|.
$$
Then $E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=E(x_3,x_2,x_1,x_4)$ if and only if $\|x_1-x_2\|=\|x_3-x_2\|$, so $E$ is not invariant under the permutation $(1,3)$.

In fact, any
$$
E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\|x_1-x_2\|+F\big((\|x_i-x_j\|)_{i<j}\big),
$$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}$ is permutation-invariant will work.

Comment: I upvoted, but one thing occured to me. Don't you need to use the squared norm to make $E$ smooth?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For a moment I forgot about that regularity assumption. But as you suggest, this doesn't matter much.